# Re-creating .vimrc key mappings in Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, evil, vim-emulation, spacemacs

I've been using vim for a while (though I'm only a basic user) and I've been trying out Emacs (specifically spacemacs).

I have remapped `H` and `L` to go to the start / end of the line by adding the following at the end of `~/.emacs.d/spacemacs/config.el`

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "H" "^")
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "L" "$")
```

I have other mappings in my `.vimrc` that I really want to transfer for familiar functionality, but I'm not sure how to do this.

For example I have tried adding the following line to `~/.emacs.d/spacemacs/config.el` (which doesn't work)

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "jf" "<ESC>")
```

How could I transfer that and the rest of my mappings over to emacs/spacemacs?

Comment: You will have to learn about Emacs and Spacemacs, by reading documentation. Nobody is going to convert your configuration for you - but if you have specific problems, then there are always people around to help you.

Comment: @tarsius I'm not posting a whole config / asking anyone to do that... I'm just confused that the first example (`H` and `L` mappings) worked whereas the other one didn't. The scope of this question is pretty narrow

Comment: Ah, sorry I mostly missed the part about this only being about key bindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This answer is more focused on Spacemacs, so it won't give a general answer about Vim-style mappings in Emacs.)

If you define `jf` in the `insert-state` map, then you won't be able to insert `j` any more. Simulating `ESC` in `insert-state` by quickly pressing a sequence of keys is a non-trivial task. There are several packages for this, `keychord.el` is one of them, I guess it is the best known one but there are some edge cases with evil. So for spacemacs I made [the `evil-escape` package](https://github.com/syl20bnr/evil-escape) to support the `ESC` use case (and much more). You can set the sequence to `jf` by setting the variable `evil-escape-key-sequence` to `"jf"` in the `dotspacemacs/init` function of the dotfile.

There is another macro available in Spacemacs to mimic some easy remapping in VimL, it is called `evil-map`, the source code is:

```
    (defmacro evil-map (state key seq)
        "Map for a given STATE a KEY to a sequence SEQ of keys.
Can handle recursive definition only if KEY is the first key of SEQ.
Example: (evil-map visual \"<\" \"<gv\")"
        (let ((map (intern (format "evil-%S-state-map" state))))
          `(define-key ,map ,key
             (lambda ()
               (interactive)
               ,(if (string-equal key (substring seq 0 1))
                    `(progn
                       (call-interactively ',(lookup-key evil-normal-state-map key))
                       (execute-kbd-macro ,(substring seq 1)))
                  (execute-kbd-macro ,seq))))))
```

It can handle some recursive remapping. For now it is only used for the following:

```
  ;; Keep the region active when shifting
  (evil-map visual "<" "<gv")
  (evil-map visual ">" ">gv")
```

Comment: Where is `evil-map` defined? I can't [find it on Github](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=evil-map).

Comment: This is a macro added in spacemacs configuration.

Comment: You mean if I want it, I should copy it to my `.spacemacs`?

Comment: You should have it already if you use spacemacs, it may be only available in develop branch at this time though.

Answer (score 1):

```
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "jk" 'evil-normal-state)
```

Escape from insert mode

You need keychord for that, by the way. You can install it from your package manager.