# colemak user :: spacemacs <caps lock> key-chord f d [hit f then d really fast]

Tags: key-bindings, evil, spacemacs

Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127591/using-caps-lock-as-esc-in-mac-os-x I remapped **caps lock** (51) to **esc** (53).

I think it was actually esc + :
(: is shift-; on qwerty but shift-p on colemak)

---

As a vim user,

I always hit **caps lock** to exit insert or append mode.

Save was **caps lock w return**

---

I would like  to send **fd** to exit from append or insert mode in evil-spacemacs.

Can you tell me what to stick in .spacemacs user-config or in a private layer.el to make this happen?

linked question - [Recreating .vimrc in spacemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12287/re-creating-vimrc-key-mappings-in-emacs?rq=1) more [Vim Emulation](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.vim-emulation/2000.)
Why isn't there a nice webpage explaining how to rebind evil for all the vim to spacemacs migratory birds?

Comment: This might be 1/2 of the answer http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

Comment: It's a little hard to follow this post, but I think you might mean: [Using 'jk' to exit insert mode with key-chord or anything else](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19961/using-jk-to-exit-insert-mode-with-key-chord-or-anything-else).

Comment: begin pseudo-lisp  (defun my-capslock ()
  "Read a char.  If not`w' then invoke `evil-normal-state'.  Else (save file)"
  (interactive)
  (let ((ch  (read-char-exclusive)))
    (if (eq ?w ch)
        (message "file saved to %s") ;; (evil-normal-state)
      (insert "j" (string ch)))))

(global-set-key "<caps lock>" 'my-capslock)